# How to give each Category a color?

Tags: python, json, if-statement, colors

We have a code to draw circles on the Location on the map with the name of each category. Now the circles and text are one color. How do we get them in different color's by category? Example: Category Garden: Blue, Category Stone: Grey.

So far the code:

```
size(1500,800)
background(1)
nofill()
stroke('#f91')
pen(.2)
fill('#f91', 0.05)
rotate(90)

font("Avenir", "bold", 10)
align('left')


def mapValue(value, fromMin, fromMax, toMin, toMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    fromSpan = fromMax - fromMin
    toSpan = toMax - toMin

    # Convert the from range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - fromMin) / float(fromSpan)

    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the to range.
    return toMin + (valueScaled * toSpan)

def xOfDot(lon):
    return mapValue(lon, -100, 100, 0, WIDTH)

def yOfDot(lat):
    return mapValue(lat, -90, 90, HEIGHT, 0)


with open('theft-alerts.json', 'r') as inputFile:
    data = json.load(inputFile)

print len(data)

artworksPerCity = {}

for stolenArt in data:
    if stolenArt.has_key('Category'):
        city = stolenArt['Category']
        if stolenArt.has_key('nItemsStolen'):
            numbersStolen = int(stolenArt['nItemsStolen'])
            if artworksPerCity.has_key(city):
                # Adjust the value stored for this city
                artworksPerCity[city] = artworksPerCity[city] + numbersStolen
            else:
                # Create new key with new value
                artworksPerCity[city] = numbersStolen
            # Draw circle on the map
            radius = artworksPerCity[city] /2
            x = xOfDot(stolenArt['Lon'])
            y = yOfDot(stolenArt['Lat'])
            arc(x, y, radius) 
            text(city, x, y)

print artworksPerCity
```

Comment: For a specific answer, you will need to describe what graphics library you're using. You've got a bunch of pretty useless tags on this question (there's no `json` to be seen, for instance), please replace them with relevant ones!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of what I intend to include in my pure python data utility.

```
def hexidecimalDiget(n,deHex = false):
    if(n<0):
        print "negitive values not supported by call to hexidecimalDiget("+str(n)+")"
        return None
    elif(n < 10):
        return str(n)
    elif(n < 15):
        return ["a","b","c","d","e"][n-10]
    elif(n in ["a","b","c","d","e"]):
        if deHex:
            return ["a","b","c","d","e"].index(n)
        return n
    else:
        print "call to hexidecimalDiget("+str(n)+") not supported!"
        return None

def colorFormHexArray(arr):
    if len(arr)!=3 and len(arr)!=6:
        print "invalid length for color on call to colorFormHexArray("+str(arr)+")"
        return None
    elif None in arr:
        print "cannot make color from None arguments in "+str(arr)
        return None
    else:
        ret = "#"
        for k in arr:
            if(type(k) == list):
                for k2 in k:
                    ret+=hexidecimalDiget(k)
            else:
            ret+=hexidecimalDiget(k)
        return ret

def arrayFromColor(c):
    c = c.replace("#","")
    col = []
    for n,k in enumerate(c):
        if(len(c) == 3):
            col.append([hexidecimalDiget(k,deHex = True)])
        elif(len(c) == 6):
            col.append([hexidecimalDiget(c[(n+1)*2-2],deHex = True),hexidecimalDiget(c[(n+1)*2-2],deHex = True)])
    return(col)

def intFromHexPair(hp):
    ret = 0
    for n,k in enumerate(hp):
        digBase = 16**(len(hp)-n-1)
        ret+=digBase*hexidecimalDiget(hp[0],deHex = True)
    return ret

def hexPairFromInt(I,minDigits = 1,maxDigits = 256):
    if I<0:
        print "negitive numbers not supported by hexPairFromInt"
    k= 0
    while(16**(k+1) <= I):
        k+=1
    if k < minDigits:
        k = minDigits
    if k > minDigits:
        print("maxDigitsExceeded")
    ret = []
    while k>=0
        dig = 16**k
        ret.append(hexidecimalDiget(int(I)%(dig))
        I -= dig
        k-=1
    return ret

def specColor(start,end,bottom,top):
    start = arrayFromColor(start)
    end = arrayFromColor(end)
    def ret(v):
        if( v<start or c>end ):
            print("value out of range "+str([start,end]))
            return('#aa0000') #eyo <- error red
        else:
            starts = [intFromHexPair(k) for k in start]
            ends = [intFromHexPair(hp) for k in end]
            normalized = (v-bottom)/(top-bottom)
            return colorFormHexArray([hexPairFromInt(int((starts[n]-ends[n])*normalized),minDigits = 1,maxDigits = 256) for n,k in enumerate(starts)])
    return ret
```

This seems excessive and hasn't even been slightly tested yet (just a stetch up atm) but I'll be testing and incorporating this code here tonight :: http://krewn.github.io/KPlot/